# Rotation & Orientation Problems in Storyboard

Tags: objective-c, rotation, orientation, storyboard

I have a universal application created in storyboard mode. It is set-up to automatically rotate to the current orientation. I have attempted to disable some orientations in iPhone-mode but it does not work when I test in the simulator.

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
// Return YES for supported orientations
if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
    return ((interfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight) || (interfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft));
} else {
    return YES;
}
}
```

Also, when the iPad is rotated, it should go through the following code BUT all I get is a black screen.

```
- (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
{
[super willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:toInterfaceOrientation duration:duration];

if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
    if (toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight) {
        self.view = landscape;
        self.view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(deg2rad*(90));
        self.view.bounds = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 1024.0, 748.0);
    } else if (toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft) {
        self.view = landscape;
        self.view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(deg2rad*(-90));
        self.view.bounds = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 1024.0, 748.0);
    } else {
        self.view = portrait;
        self.view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(0);
        self.view.bounds = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 768.0, 1004.0);
    }
} else {

}
}
```

Why are all these problems arising here? I have tried the code in different Xcode projects without storyboards ad it works fine. What is going on and how can I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should create two separate stackoverflow questions.  I will answer your first question here.

Consider this line from your code:

```
return ((interfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight) || (interfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft));
```

- If the orientation is `Right`, then your code reduces to `return (Right != Right) || (Right != Left)`, which always returns true.
- If the orientation is `Left`, then your code reduces to `return (Left != Right) || (Left != Left)`, which always returns true.
- If the orientation is `Up`, then your code reduces to `return (Up != Right) || (Up != Left)`, which always returns true.
- If the orientation is `Down`, then your code reduces to `return (Down != Right) || (Down != Left)`, which always returns true.

It's not clear which orientations you want to allow and which you want to exclude.  If you want to allow only portrait orientations, do this:

```
return UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(interfaceOrientation);
```

If you want to allow only landscape orientations, do this:

```
return UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(interfaceOrientation);
```